# quarkus build quarkus.run.jar without any content but the manifest file

Tags: quarkus

I just upgraded my project to the latest quarkus 3.6.3 and java 21, and now it seems I cannot get a working quarkus-run.jar. I do get the file in target/quarkus-app but it only has the manifest file, otherwise it's empty. I also do get an complete jar but without the manifest file in target/quarkus-app/app. But I would like to get the combined jar as usual. There are no errors during build. It seems to be an environment problem as other projects, including a brand new random project from quarkus.io has the same problem. I'm building with 'mvn install' Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a [MRE], e.g. in form of a github repository? - What do you mean by "combined jar"? Do you mean the uber-jar? If so: from where did you upgrade?  We can build an uber-jar by setting `quarkus.package.type` to `uber-jar` (either in the `application.properties` or in the `pom.xml`, see [here (`quarkus.io`)](https://quarkus.io/guides/maven-tooling#uber-jar-maven)).

Comment: Hi i just mean a regular quarkus.run.jar including classes and a manifest file, will try to make a reproducible